# Dynamic Control Display from .NET web service XML in iPad

Tags: iphone, .net, ios, web-services, ipad

I need to display web controls like checkbox, Pick List, TextBox, Label, Button, etc. in an iPad dynamically using a .NET web service.

For that I have to read XML coming from a .NET web service and display controls in the iPad accordingly.

Also, I need to perform validation dynamically on these dynamically added controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is useful for you

Check this

```
https://github.com/jonathanellis/pegasus
```